# Join three tables in database Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, join

I have three tables cases,users,user_role , in cases table there are user_id and user_role_id , I want to join two tables users and user_role with cases to convert user_id to his name in users table and convert user_role_id to his name in user_role table , I success in one of them , but when join another table i faild

in models/cases_model.php

```
function get_all()
    {

    $this->db->where('C.is_archived',0);
    $this->db->select('C.*,U.name client');
        $this->db->join('users U', 'U.id = C.client_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('user_role UR', 'UR.id = C.city_case', 'LEFT');
    return $this->db->get('cases C')->result();

    }
```

in controllers/cases.php

```
function index(){

        $data['cases'] = $this->cases_model->get_all();
        $data['courts'] = $this->cases_model->get_all_courts();
        $data['clients'] = $this->cases_model->get_all_clients();
        $data['locations'] = $this->location_model->get_all();
        $data['stages'] = $this->case_stage_model->get_all();
        $data['city'] = $this->cases_model->get_name_city();
        $data['page_title'] = lang('case');
        $data['body'] = 'case/list';
        $this->load->view('template/main', $data);  
    }
```

in view/list.php

```
<?php if(isset($cases)):?>
     <tbody>
      <?php $i=1;foreach ($cases as $new){?>
       <tr class="gc_row">
      <td><?php echo $i?></td>

        <td class="small-col">                          
        <?php if($new->is_starred==0){ ?>
        <a href="" at="90" class="Privat"><span style="display:none"><?php echo $new->id?></span>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a>
        <?php 
            }else{
            ?>
        <a href="" at="90" class="Public"><span style="display:none"><?php echo $new->id?></span>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
        <?php
         }?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $new->title?></td>
        <td><?php echo $new->case_no?></td>
        <td><?php echo $new->client?></td>
        <td><?php echo $new->city_case?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not doing sql part here. but if CI's method is blocker for your task then you should use simple solution instead of CI's PDO method.

simple word use

```
 $this->db->query({some complex query as String});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to get desired output

```
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('Cases c'); 
            $this->db->join('Users u', 'u.user_id=c.user_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('user_role r', 'r.user_id=c.user_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where('c.user_id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

now,here in join user_id is consiodered as primary key..and one more thing you can replace * with required column name!

Thanks..